# Is it possible for jQuery cookies to expire like session variables?

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

I know this question has been asked a thousand times but none of the answers really give me what I'm looking for. I am using [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to store some information, but I want them to expire when the browser closes. `window.unload` is not a viable option (read: doesn't work.)

My question is this: is it *actually possible* to have the cookies set to expire when the browser closes, like a session? If so, does anyone know how?

**Update:** Turns out it's quite simple, instead of passing expiry: 0 (which didn't work), just don't pass any expiry at all. Well, this explains why there wasn't many questions.

Thanks all.

Comment: HTTP has to send expiry dates. Check the RFCs and the implementation if it sends the correct dates. (Has to be in the past.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out it's quite simple, instead of passing expiry: 0 (which didn't work), just don't pass any expiry at all. Well, this explains why there wasn't many questions.

So instead of passing expiry with the flags like so:

```
$.cookie(key, value, { expiry: 0, domain: '', path: '' });
```

You just omit the expiry value:

```
$.cookie(key, value, { domain: '', path: '' });
```

And it works. It's such a simple thing, that it confused me.

But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in the [RFC 2965 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965). That said it would be possible if you set the "Discard" property in your cookie handling code **and** if the browser supports it.

That said: jQuery cookie doesn't support the Discard-property. You would have to extend the [jQuery-Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) code like so (it's about line 57 in the original file):

```
        return (document.cookie = [
            config.raw ? key : encodeURIComponent(key),
            '=',
            config.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                            options.discard ? '; Discard=' + options.discard : '',
            options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use a default setup like this

```
 $.cookie.defaults = { path: '/', expires: 365 };
```

then you need to use the following attribute for each cookie value

```
$.cookie(key, value, { expires: null });
```